# Calculate similarity score between multidimensional arrays (Tensor)

Tags: arrays, matlab, multidimensional-array

I have two tensors A and B of sizes 1500 x 1000 x 500. how can I calculate similarity index between them?

I have applied the following formula:

```
relerr = frob((A - B))./frob(A);
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your definition for similarity score.
Simply you can use Euclidean distance as follow:

```
x = 20;
y = 10;
z = 12;
A = randi([1, 10], x, y, z);
B = randi([1, 10], x, y, z);
C = (A-B).^2;
similarity = sqrt(sum(C(:)));
```

or you can define other similarity measures like [Correlation coefficeint](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/281377-correlation-coefficeint-as-a-similarity-index).

Comment: And the best score would be zero?

Comment: For Euclidean distance, yes.